# Need Help Cross Referencing a File Tree with a Bill of Materials in Excel

Tags: excel, automation, generator, cross-reference

I am an intern at an engineering firm, and I have been given the task of compiling a list of missing CAD files from a file directory. I have been using the Bill of Materials to check manually each file, but with the bigger products having 8000+ files, I was wondering if there was a way do do this checking automatically. I have the BOM in Excel now, and I am noting if both the CAD model and CAD drawings are there individually for each part number by hand. The process is long enough when checking for 300 parts, I cant imagine doing 8000+!

My question is this:
Is there any way to automatically search for file names in excel vs the file tree where it is noted back in excel if the file is there or not?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how many items you are dealing with, you likely want to load both the file names that you are looking for into an array, and the name of the files found in your directory into a separate array. then do the comparisons inside of there. this is a basic program that checks for a single file in a single directory to give you some direction.

edit just realized that this is sort of the wrong direction as you likely need to load the file names and such into an array. I can try to work on this later tonight.

```
Sub scanDirectory()

    Dim path As String
    Dim currentPath As String

    Dim nameOfFile As String

    nameOfFile = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)

    'put the path to your folder here along with an \
    path = "Z:\New folder\"

    currentPath = Dir(path)

    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        Debug.Print currentPath
        If currentPath = nameOfFile Then
            Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 2) = "FILEFOUND"
            Exit Do 
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I am having an error when I try to run however= Compile Error: Exit For not within For...Next, with the Exit For highlighted

Comment: should be Exit Do not Exit For. Edited. This only looks for a single file, but structure will basically be same. as I said given the amount of matches you likely will want to load names of files as they are in ws into an array, and probably load the names of files inside folder u are searching into an array, and compare

Comment: Great thanks! how would you suggest adding the file names to an array? I am now running into a 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range on line 8

Comment: did you change "Z:\New folder\" into your own path?

Comment: I figured the problem, the Sheet name wasn't correct.